# Upon logging into sqlplus why does it always print the username?

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

Upon logging into sqlplus why does it always print the username in linux?

```
$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Apr 7 06:32:57 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: scott

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

USER is "SCOTT"
```

I don't want to print that the "USER is "SCOTT" ".

One clue is that the message "USER is", I can see it in

```
/software/oracle/cli-11.02.00.04/sqlplus/mesg/sp2us.msg

 sqlplus/mesg/sp2us.msg:572:00291,0, "USER is \"%s\"\n"
```

do I need to change any settings somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not default SQL*Plus behavior. So you probably have a SHOW USER command (which does it) in your personal `login.sql` or the global `glogin.sql` files.

Have a look in your `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin` sub-directory for the `glogin.sql` file.

`login.sql` can be in any directory in the `$SQLPATH`, but SQL*Plus starts its search in the current directory. So with luck the file will be in somewhere sensible such as your client `$ORACLE_HOME`.

SQL*PLus configuration is covered in the documentation. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1132910).

> "in `/upapps/oracle/dba/tools/login.sql` ... there is show user command ... so is that the reason? "

Yep. SQL*Plus  runs `login.sql` every time we connect, for instance to use `SET SQLPROMPT` to change the prompt. Having `SCOTT>` as your prompt is probably more useful than showing the user you've just connected as.

> " can I override login.sql and glogin.sql so that everytime I connect to sqlplus it will execute my login.sql and glogin.sql?"

You can't override `glogin.sql` because there is only one of them (*g* is for "global"). But there can multiple versions of `login.sql`. As I said above, SQL*Plus starts its search for the file in the current directory. So you need to create a `login.sql` file in a location where you have write privileges (e.g. `$HOME/naren`) and then always start SQL*Plus from there.

---

> " is there any way we can acheive this even when we run from different folder? "

If you can't write a file where you start SQL*Plus and you can't start SQL*Plus where you can write a file it becomes a political problem not a technical problem. You need to negotiate with the people who administer your Oracle environment.

Or just learn to live with it. This is a fairly trivial thing; I can't believe I've put so much time and energy into this topic :) So if `show user` is the greatest annoyance in your working day you should count your blessings.

Comment: I don't see any content in glogin.sql.. all of it's lines are started with --.
I assume those were comments

Comment: @naren - how about a `login.sql`? The command will be `show user` (which is linked to sp2us.msg you found), unless that functionality is being duplicated another way.

Comment: @naren - you have a default `glogin.sql` script so you need to look for a  `login.sql` in some other location. I have expanded my answer for you.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks, but I don't see any .login in my home directory.

Comment: @APC, thanks.. yes I see it in "/upapps/oracle/dba/tools/login.sql" and as AlexPoole mentioned there is show user command in it, so is that the reason?

Comment: the fix you have suggested, i.e to remove 'show user' will work it seems but I don't have permissions to change it, can I override login.sql and glogin.sql so that everytime I connect to sqlplus it will execute my login.sql and glogin.sql?

Comment: What ever you have suggested is working, actually I have done that before your update, but it's not working because I am starting sqlplus from a different directory. When I run from home directory I don't have any issues.. is there any way we can acheive this even when we run from different folder apart from creating login.sql in each folder?

Comment: @APC I really appreciate and the same time I am sorry that you have to spend some much time on this topic, actually our dev servers have been upgraded and each time we run sqlplus we are seeing the output which is effecting our test scripts so that the expected output is not matching with actual output (because of USER is .....) and we have 100's of different folders where we are running sqlplus as it's a huge project. We have to find a way to change the /upapps/oracle/dba/tools/login.sql as you suggested. Thanks for your valuable information, can't upvote your answer as well :( Im not allowed